# When API returns 400 status code, Getting error message using Reactjs fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I'm using `Reactjs` web application. There I'm calling `Nodejs` RestAPI.

When API returns status code 400, I can't get it error message which is coming from API.

I'm not able to get the `errorDesc` from API response.

**400 error API response**

```
{
  "errorCode": "M400",
  "message": "Invalid Request",
  "errorDesc": "missing required first name field"
}
```

**React code:**

```
fetch(URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    if (response.status == 400) {
                        Modal.error({
                            className: "ErrorModal",
                            title: "Error",
                            content: "Invalid Request.",
                        });
                    }
                    return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(status => {
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of the error response, you need to read the body of the response.

it might not be `json`, but if you happen to know it is, you would just use `response.json()` just like you do for the actual valid result.

Or, use `response.text()` to get the text version, which you can still parse as json afterwards if you want.

One possible approach

```
fetch(URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    if (response.status == 400) {
                      return response.json().then((error) => {
                      
                        Modal.error({
                            className: "ErrorModal",
                            title: error.message || 'Invalid Request',
                            content: error.errorDesc || '',
                        });
                        return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
                      });
                    } else {
                      return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
                    }
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```